# AutoHotKey: Can a server identify a click vs. a direct link access?

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

I am writing an automation tool to access a certain website. There are 200 links to click and perform copying, and storing them. But in order to get to the links, I have to do {Tab} many times, and then press enter to trigger the page to load to the result page.

I am able to obtain the link's url directly, but my question is, would that website able to tell I am accessing the page directly via http bar vs. simulating the mouse click or keyboard to trigger the load?

- Physically controlling mouse and keyboard to click the links (This is done via Autohotkey, with some simulated delays sleep timers).
- Get the link from looking at the source code, and then entering the direct HTTP link on the address bar and hit enter

I am trying to do things automatically without triggering attention. There are a lot of manual process that is like copy and pasting, for few hundred times per week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the level of advancement of a back-end. Generally if you will truly simulate mouse moves, add random timing between actions etc. It won't be able to tell that you're not human. I don't think you can achieve that with AHK. You can perform some tests on Googles reCaptcha:

[reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)